# Mysql date range query only check date without check month and year

Tags: php, mysql, date, date-range

I want in select records based on date condition of day only without checking month and year.

```
Table structure 
------------------------------------
id | user_id  | amount | created_on
------------------------------------
```

If I select date 15-April to 25-April, Then I need record between 15-April to 25-April, 15-March to 25-March and so on..

It seems quite easy with fetch day from date and compare it with

```
Select sum(amount) from sales where DATEFORMAT(created_on, %d) >= 15 and DATEFORMAT(created_on, %d) <=25
```

But how to find records when i select date 28-March to 5-April, then I need data of 28-February to 5-March, 28-January to 5-February.. and so on

Comment: You cannot check it without month in this case :)

Comment: @Goikiu what about data of 28 February, 28 January and so on?

Comment: I think that you cannot achieve this without using the full date. Using the full date will however be different from what you asked ;)

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

If you are using php with it. you can compare minimum and maximum dates and change your query like this:

Attempt #1:

```
    $min_date = 15;
    $max_date = 25;
```

Attempt #2:

```
    $min_date = 28;
    $max_date = 5;
```

Script:

```
    if($min_date < $max_date)
    {
        $query = "Select sum(amount) from sales where DATEFORMAT(created_on, %d) >= $min_date and DATEFORMAT(created_on, %d) <=$max_date";    
    }
    else
    {
        $query = "Select sum(amount) from sales where DATEFORMAT(created_on, %d) >= $min_date OR DATEFORMAT(created_on, %d) <=$max_date"; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL BETWEEN Operator

```
Select sum(amount) from sales where created_on BETWEEN '2017/03/28'  and '2017/04/05'
```

Source [SQL Between Operator](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp)

Comment: the op asked for a solution without year and month check.

Comment: You are comparing month also... what about data of 28 February to 05 March, 28 January to 05 February, and so on?

Comment: You can't achieve this using MySQL only.

You can get the sum by looping in PHP. Getting specific dates you want and you could process the results once done. You could still use this SQL Query tho in querying.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?  (X1 and X2 are your values)

```
Select sum(amount) 
from sales 
where 
    (1= CASE WHEN X2>=X1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AND DATEFORMAT(created_on, %d) >= X1 and DATEFORMAT(created_on, %d) <=x2)
OR (1= CASE WHEN X2<X1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AND ( DATEFORMAT(created_on, %d) >=X1 OR DATEFORMAT(created_on, %d) <=X2))
```

Answer (score -1):

*use this to extract only date from your timestamp and then compare it with ur requirement.*

**select SUBSTRING(date(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 9, 2) , SUBSTRING(date('2017-04-27' ), 9, 2)**

OUTPUT: 27 , 27

*Cheers!!*